# Alternatively shift columns and rows of a 2D array

Tags: code-golf, array

#### Objective

Given a 2D array of any size, write a program or function to shift alternatively the columns and rows

#### Example

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
```

All elements in the **first** column shift **down** one row, the **second** column shift **up** one row, the **third** shift **down** one row and so on, wrapping when they reach the edge.

```
k g m i o
a l c n e
f b h d j
```

All elements in the **first** row shift to the **right**, the **second** to to the **left**, the **third** to the **right** etc., wrapping when they reach the edge.

```
o k g m i
l c n e a
j f b h d
```

I will follow the tradition of selecting the shortest working code as the best answer

Comment: Can the array be any size, or specifically 3x5?

Comment: i was looking for any filled 2D array. sorry for not mentioning it. Ill add an edit

Comment: To be honest, the improper formatting makes the question look as if it was an off-topic question from a lazy SO user.

Comment: (BTW, don't accept an answer too soon)

Comment: I apologise for that. Please feel free to edit it and properly format it

Comment: @kshishoo Welcome to PPCG, I've made minor edits on the question, feel free to rollback if you don't agree with them.

Comment: @rod Your edits were quite helpful, i will try and keep the same format in mind should i post other questions/challenges

Comment: @kshishoo For future challenges you can use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1)  to check for duplicates and/or gather some feedback before posting on main site

Comment: but i not see the test cases... where are? the ii Matrix it is a test case?

Comment: It's frowned upon to accept an answer so quickly.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer my apologies. i thought 48 hours would be enough, How long should i leave the question up before selecting an answer. (i can also still unselect the best answer and wait)

Comment: @kshishoo I'd wait a week, but I'd recommend not accepting an answer at all, that could discourage some people from answering after an answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
‼ozṙİ_T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDnvyqhztnHtkQH/L///9opcSk5JRUJR2ltPSMzCwgnZ2Tm5evFAsA)

### Explanation

```
‼ozṙİ_T  Implicit input: a list of lists.
‼        Do this twice:
      T   Transpose,
 oz       then zip with
    İ_    the infinite list [-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,..
   ṙ      using rotation. This rotates the rows in alternating directions.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
,!tZy:oEq2&YS
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X0exJKrSKt@10EgtMvj//2j1xKTklFR1a/W09IzMLCCdnZObl68eCwA)

#### Explanation

```
,        % Do twice
  !      %   Transpose. Takes input implicitly the first time
  t      %   Duplicate
  Zy     %   Size. Gives a vector with numbers of rows and of columns
  :      %   Range from 1 to the first entry of the vector (number of rows)
  o      %   Parity: gives 0 or 1 for eacn entry
  Eq     %   Times 2, minus 1: transforms 0 into -1
  2      %   Push 2
  &YS    %   Circularly shift along the second dimension. This shifts the
         %   first row by 1 (that is, to the right), the second by -1 (to
         %   the left), etc.
         % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>26, 21</strike> 19 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to miles

```
(|."_1~_1^#\)@|:^:2
```

### Explanation:

`^:2` - repeate twice the following:

`@|:` - transpose and

`#\`  - find the length ot the prefixes (1, 2, 3 ... rows)

`_1^` - raise -1 to the above powers, creating a list of alternating -1 1 -1 1...

`|."_1~` - rotate each row of the input array with offset from the above list

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWr0lOIN6@IN45RjNB1qrOKsjP5rcilwpSZn5CukKRgrmKqoJyYlp6SmpWdkZmXn5Oblq/8HAA)

### Original version:

```
(($_1 1"0)@#|."0 1])@|:^:2
```

### How it works

`^:2` - repeate twice the following:

`|:` - transpose and

`|."0 1]` - rotate each row of the input array, offsets in the list:

`@#` - the number of rows in the array

`($_1 1"0)` - alternate _1 1 (3 -> _1 1 _1)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NTRU4g0VDJUMNB2Ua/SUDBQMYzUdaqzirIz@a3IpcKUmZ@QrpCkYK5iqqCcmJaekpqVnZGZl5@Tm5av/BwA)

Comment: You can generate the `_1 1..` using ``(|."_1~_1^2|#\)@|:^:2`` also

Comment: @miles Thanks, that's a great piece of code!

Comment: @miles in fact I don't need the `2|` part

Comment: Yes, you actually don't, that's another 2 bytes saved.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 55 bytes

```
Nest[MapIndexed[RotateLeft[#,(-1)^#2]&,Thread@#]&,#,2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixCsIwFAXQXxEConAddBdcBRURt5DCs3k1sSaV5g2FkG@P2Q4nkDgOJL6nmlbHeuMk@kq/c7S8sNWPSUj4woNohc1uv@3UwazxdDOTPalGhRb1PvsoOumcCS/0sOCCPOANB49P84gvAiKmUoypfw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 83 bytes

```python
x=input()
exec'x=[l[i%2*2-1:]+l[:i%2*2-1]for i,l in enumerate(zip(*x))];'*2
print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclBDsIgEIXhfU/Bxgy0uJBlTU9CWNQ6taMUCKEJennMRDdf/peX3mWLwbRWJwrpKFJ1WHGBOllv6WR6c76MbvB2/A@3xixIe0FBYDh2zHNB@aEk@6qUu0JvupQpFFFbsxZm0AJuzMLcGQSnhYWV@8FsDDHP3/Xi9szOBCaCc18)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 30 bytes

Prompts for screen input of a 2d array

```
((↑⍴m)⍴¯1 1)⌽((1↓⍴m)⍴¯1 1)⊖m←⎕
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>116</s>  76 bytes

```js
m=>(g=m=>m[0].map((_,x)=>m.map(_=>m[y++%h][x],h=m.length,y=x&1||h-1)))(g(m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcxLCoMwFIXhuatw0ibBKHUB6UZCkFRjos1DVIqCe7enQgffhZ8Dd9QfvbTzMK1lTJ05e3EG8aRW4Ab5UFXQE6UN3xj6iuY37EVxc0puijsRKm@iXR3fxXavj8OVNWOMWhoYO9sUl@RN5ZOlPZVZnkuiCScvaKEDQxS/hh5hwcEA4394IzwEiJCIyhS@fwE)

#### Commented

```js
m => (                 // m[] = input matrix
  g = m =>             // g is the main helper function taking a matrix m[]
    m[0].map((_, x) => // for each column at position x in m[]:
      m.map(_ =>       //   for each row of m[]:
        m[y++ % h][x], //     yield the x-th value of the row (y mod h) and increment y
        h = m.length,  //     h = number of rows
        y = x & 1      //     start with y = 1 if x is odd,
            || h - 1   //     or h - 1 if x is even
      )                //   end of inner map()
  )                    // end of outer map()
)(g(m))                // invoke g twice on the input matrix
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes

```apl
{(¯1 1⍴⍨≢⍵)⌽(¯1 1⍴⍨≢⍉⍵)⊖⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqjUPrDRUMH/VuedS74lHnoke9WzUf9ezFEO0ES3RNA1K1QJ0KxgqmINm@qY4A)

Prefix Dfn.

#### How?

```apl
{(¯1 1⍴⍨≢⍵)⌽(¯1 1⍴⍨≢⍉⍵)⊖⍵}⍝ Main function, prefix. Input matrix is ⍵.
                        ⊖⍵}⍝ Rotate the columns of ⍵ according to the left arg:
            (       ⍉⍵)    ⍝ Transpose ⍵ (makes a 3x5 matrix become 5x3)
                   ≢       ⍝ Tally (yields the number of rows of the matrix)
                  ⍨        ⍝ Swap arguments of the following fn/op
                 ⍴         ⍝ Shape
             ¯1 1          ⍝ This vector. This yields a vector of ¯1 1 with size = number of columns of ⍵.
          ⌽                ⍝ Rotate the rows of ⍵ according to the left arg:
{(¯1 1⍴⍨≢⍵)                ⍝ Does the same as the preceding expression, without transposing ⍵.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes (SBCS)

```apl
{⍵⌽⍨¯1*⍳≢⍵}∘⍉⍣2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZK7jtQwFIb7eYpf02yClhGe2VmW7UE0QDMv4JmcIYbEjmxHIUK0K3ZFEBRINDRsQ0eBKGl4FL/IcOwss0CDtohin8v3n4tlU90uelmZp7vdyzB8D29@hOHLz6/iVhi@hfPPbHoVXn8Mw3kYLue7XRg@4fGT1f1TPDQdvEEtnxN601qYTsOT89hIR27CkfHDqiSQdCp6Otnvc3xJNZSLd0eNtNITdFuvyTp0ypdwjdyQg9QFOisbhmzKRLSsrLRTBYHzSDOJBZGpGc2QsTfPD9G0PkrEYMfRMLYgm2BbpWVV9WgsNaSLhJyGs/fh4mw6wwNjQS9k3VR0yAAuUFor@9N9PxDAHFgAR8ByNB0Dd4ET4B7EnWQSAmIOsYA4gljuk11p2qrAmrgl5T1pVCrNQrlrhbGWTLDMgkWWeXbM@JMEz7O/yfmfc9Z41vKUrxrDNG5jGgec1hKn8U8v0X4ztZT2SPJAt63eeGU0Mteua@Ucn9m/5fLf4f9PaSStuABey2/WZJIqHQlvP/D/4CBcXI7HbQRcp109s8mNe/gF)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>94</s> 91 bytes

```
a=>(g=a=>a[0].map((_,i)=>(b=a.map(a=>a[i]),i%2?[...b.slice(1),b[0]]:[b.pop(),...b])))(g(a))
```

There's probably a golfier way to do the rotation...

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

```
L.e.>b^_1k.Tbyy
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L.e.%3Eb%5E_1k.Tbyy&input=%5B%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27c%27%2C%20%27d%27%2C%20%27e%27%5D%2C%20%5B%27f%27%2C%20%27g%27%2C%20%27h%27%2C%20%27i%27%2C%20%27j%27%5D%2C%20%5B%27k%27%2C%20%27l%27%2C%20%27m%27%2C%20%27n%27%2C%20%27o%27%5D%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
L.e.>b^_1k.Tbyy
L           b      Define a function on a list...
          .T       ... which transposes it...
 .e.>b^_1k         ... and rotates each row alternating left and right.
             yyQ   Apply twice to the (implicit) input array.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [q/kdb+](http://kx.com/download/), 32 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{rotate'[#:[x+:]#-1 1](+)x}/[2;]
```

**Example:**

```
q)3 5#.Q.a / reshape "a..o" into 3 row, 5 column grid
"abcde"
"fghij"
"klmno"
q){rotate'[#:[(+)x]#-1 1](+)x}/[2;]3 5#.Q.a
"okgmi"
"lcnea"
"jfbhd"
```

**Explanation:**

Flip the grid in order to apply rotation to **columns**, the second iteration flips once again thus the rotation is applied to the **rows** on the second pass.

Rotation is based a the list `-1 1 -1 1..` of the length of the row/column being rotated.

A healthy **9 bytes** have been golfed off from this *easier-to-read* version

```
{rotate'[count[flip x]#-1 1;flip x]}/[2;] / ungolfed solution
{                                  }/[2;] / perform lambda 2 times
 rotate'[                  ;      ]       / perform rotate on each-both
                            flip x        / flip x<->y of grid
                      #-1 1               / take from list -1 1
         count[flip x]                    / the length of the flipped grid
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ZJ-*ṙ"@Zµ⁺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/KS1fr4c6ZSg5Rh7Y@atz1/3D70UkPd874/z86WsFQR0HBCIiNgdgEiE1jdbgUohXMgExzILYAYksdBUMDsLAhULUhULUhULUhULWhaWwsAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 93 bytes

```
import StdEnv,StdLib
k=[0,1:k]
^l=[[[last a:init a],tl a++[hd a]]!!b\\a<-transpose l&b<-k]
```

```
^o^
```

As a partial function literal, that happens to look like a face.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY49C4MwGIR3f0WkUAcV2lV0a4eCm2OM8Bq/UpM3EmPBP9806NDpuTuO47jsAZ3S3SZ7okCgE2rRxpLKdk/8JB6laIO5oLfkns0saGRBKZWwWgKZQOHBEisJxDGdOm9YGLZ1DXlqDeC66LUn8trm6cxcZcHY4ELAGNhJQSiNoOVdH7GERsM4ifehZqlQR4z55rAht0KjLze6CYp/cGy4Lx8kjKtLX6V77AhK8NOcv38)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
2FøvyNÉiÀëÁ}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fyO3wjrJKv8OdmYcbDq8@3Fhbq/n/f3S0eqK6joJ6EohIBhEpICJVPVZHIVo9DcROBxEZICITRGRBpLJB7BwQkQsi8kBEvnpsLAA)

**Explanation**

```
2F               # 2 times do:
  ø              # zip
   vy            # for each row(y), index(N) do:
     NÉiÀ        # if N is odd, rotate left
         ëÁ      # else rotate right
           }}    # end if and inner loop
             )   # wrap in list
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL NARS, 36 bytes, 18 chars

```
c←b∘b←{⍵⌽⍨-×-\⍳≢⍵}∘⍉
```

This {⍵⌽⍨-×-\⍳≢⍵} would rotate each row of the matrix argument follow the vector -1 1 -1 1 etc(that has its vector length the length of the argument matrix rows).  Test:

```
  ⎕←a←3 5⍴⎕A
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
  ⎕←c a
OKGMI
LCNEA
JFBHD
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71973/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-roslup).

Answer (score 0):

### bash et al, 84

Non-competing shell solution.

This is based around a function that alternates the direction of the rotation of the rows. The same procedure done on the transposed array will rotate the columns. For example `transpose | rotate | transpose | rotate`.

The alternating rotation can be done on single character arrays with `sed` like this:

```
sed -E 's/(.*) (.)$/\2 \1/; n; s/^(.) (.*)/\2 \1/'
```

The transposition can be done with `rs` or `datamash`:

```
rs -g1 -T
datamash -t' ' transpose
```

Taken together:

```
r() { sed -E 's/(.*) (.)$/\2 \1/; n; s/^(.) (.*)/\2 \1/'; }
t() { rs -g1 -T; }
<f t | r | t | r
```

Output:

```
o k g m i
l c n e a
j f b h d
```